# How to make Chakra Slider perform a method after value change

Tags: reactjs, slider, chakra-ui

**TL;DR:** I want to know how to make Chakra slider call a method after the user moves the handler and releases it. The `onChange` doesn't get called until the user clicks outside the slider (so the handler loses focus), but I need to get something performed right after the slider is moved.

**Long version:**

I'm working on a React project with Chakra UI elements. There is one part of the app which is using a reactive form, a text input field and a Chakra slider to adjust certain value. When one component changes, the change is reflected in the other component as well (e.g. if I enter a certain amount in the text field, the slider gets moved, and if I move the slider, the text field changes its value accordingly).

The slider has min and max allowed value and if anything outside that range is entered in the text field, an error message will appear.

Here's the code:

```
// In The "main" component:
<CustomSliderComponent
            form={form}
            field={FIELD_ID}
            min={MIN_ALLOWED_VALUE}
            max={MAX_ALLOWED_VALUE}
            step={STEP_VALUE}
            onBlur={() => form.validateSingleField(FIELD_ID)}
          />

// The CustomSliderComponent has this inside:    
<Slider
          {...props}
          name={field}
          id={field}
          value={value}
          onChange={(value) =>
            handleChange({
              target: { name: field, value: Number(value) },
            })
          }
        />

// And this is the slider itself:
    export const Slider = forwardRef<SliderProps, 'div'>((props, ref) => {
      return (
        <ChakraSlider ref={ref} {...props}>
          <SliderTrack>
            <SliderFilledTrack />
          </SliderTrack>
          <SliderThumb />
        </ChakraSlider>
      );
    });
```

However, there is a bug which I can't resolve.

Step 1: I enter an invalid value in the text field (less than the defined minimum or above the maximum). The `onChange` event gets fired, the custom form validation method is executed inside it, and the error message gets displayed.

Step 2: I move the slider so it gets to the allowed range. The text field value changes as well to the new (allowed) value. But when I release the mouse button, the error message is still there, and the slider's handle still has the focus. Only when I click outside the slider, it loses focus and the validation gets executed again (and the error message disappears).

Is there a way to perform the validation (or to perform *any* action) after the user finishes moving the slider handle? I tried using several event handlers, but none of them seems to be working (onAbortCapture, onChangeEnd, onDragEnd, onDragExit, onMouseLeave...)